# Py3 shutil.make_archive command runs before subprocess.Popen

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, shutil

I want to download a file then compress it. In my code, I have a subprocess command to download a file THEN I have a shutil command to compress it. But when executed, the shutil command runs first.

Note: "MyDownloadScript.pl" is a Perl script that downloads the needed file. For the purposes of this task, I have to download with this script.

```
subprocess.Popen(['perl', 'C:\\gitrepo\\BuildScripts\\MyDownloadScript.pl', '-branch', 'BranchName'])          

shutil.make_archive(('{}\\OutputZIP'.format('outputPath'), 'zip', 'C:\\startingFolder', 'startingFile.dmg')
```

Despite the ordering of the functions in the code, the shutil command always runs first. Here's what happens what I run the script in different scenarios:

1) If no files exist:

- Script complains it can't find the .dmg file
- .dmg file is downloaded after
- No ZIP produced

2) If I run the script again right afterwards (when the .dmg exists)

- ZIP file is created from .dmg
- .dmg is RE-DOWNLOADED

Why are these functions running seemingly out of order? Any ideas/suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[`subprocess.Popen()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) is non-blocking. So it spawns a process and immediately goes to the next line in your script. Try [`subprocess.call()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) instead:

```
subprocess.call(['perl', 'C:\gitrepo\BuildScripts\MyDownloadScript.pl', '-branch', 'BranchName'])          

shutil.make_archive(('{}\OutputZIP'.format('outputPath'), 'zip', 'C:\startingFolder', 'startingFile.dmg')
```